# Glucose profile - IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is Glucose Profile supported by iOS? As I could not find anywhere even in Apple documentation that iOS (CoreBluetooth) api supports glucose profile. Apple docs just say about heart rate monitors and digital thermostats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Bluetooth supports the GATT profile of Bluetooth Low Energy.   The Bluetooth SIG has adopted specifications for [a number of services](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications) that make use of the GATT profile including the Glucose Service & Glucose Profile (GLS/GLP) and the Continuous Glucose Monitoring Profile & Service (CGMS/CGMP).

Core Bluetooth in iOS doesn't include any functionality to *specifically* support these services and profiles, but they are delivered using the GATT profile, so the short answer is you can write an app to interact with a peripheral that offers the GLS or CGMS service.

Core Bluetooth doesn't offer specific support for heart-rate monitors either, but they are commonly used as an example of a BLE peripheral in the Apple documentation.  They are also supported by HealthKit

Comment: "Core Bluetooth doesn't offer specific support for heart-rate monitors either" HealthKit, though, does. Pairing a device with a BTLE HRM will make that HRM available as a source for HealthKit. Other health/fitness related devices... may... behave similarly.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about HealthKit but the question asked about Core Bluetooth